# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC model binding not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

When the `Index()` method is called, the `ItemOrVm` property is populated with data.

When I call the `Create()` method, property `ItemOrVm = null`

Why does it reset?

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
    private readonly IItemsOrRepository _itemsOrRepository;

    [BindProperty]
    public ItemOrVM? ItemOrVm { get; set; }

    public ItemsController(IItemsOrRepository itemsOrRepository, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _itemsOrRepository = itemsOrRepository;
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.OrderId = id;

        this.ItemOrVm = new ItemOrVM()
        {
            Order = _orderRepository.FirstOfDefault(u => u.Id == id),
            OrderItems = _itemsOrRepository.GetAll(u => u.OrderId == id)
        };

        return View(ItemOrVm);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create(int? orderId, int? itemId)
    {
        ViewBag.OrderId = this.ItemOrVm!.Order!.Id;

        if (itemId != null)
        {
            OrderItem orderItems = _itemsOrRepository.FirstOfDefault(u => u.Id == itemId);
            return View(orderItems);
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Similar code with different model, works on .NET 5.0

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core MVC or Web API, every request is treated as a new request and each request creates a new page object,

The following things you can use

- Session
- Application data
- Define a global variable in `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs` as a static type
- TempData
- Viewbag